# replace black (and proportionally grey) with fixed colour using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have a pdf/png/jpeg which is black-and-white. I want to make it blue-and-white or red-and-white or something-and-white. There are grey tones and I want them to be handled proportionately.

In gimp I can get the desired effect by `Invert` then `Colorify` (to the inverse of the colour I actually want) then `Invert` again. Which is not an ideal workflow.

Mathematically, if each pixel value is V from  0.0 (black) to 1.0 (white) then the final pixel should be `(1-V)*colour`.

If the input is pdf or another vector type, raster output at a chosen resolution is acceptable.

How can I do this with Imagemagick command line tools on Linux?

Comment: Maybe write about what you've tried based off `ImageMagick`'s documentation/manpage, and how that's not working?